# How to improve insert performance on a billion row table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I have billion row table that no longer fits in the memory.

When I insert new rows in bulk, the overhead of recounting the primary index, kills the performance. I HAVE to have this index because otherwise SELECT statements are really slow. But since the inserts come in a random order, with each row inserted, the data has to be written in different area of the disk.

And since the HDD is capped at 200 IO operations per second, this slows the inserting to a crawl.

Can I "have my cake and eat it" at the same time in this situation? Maybe by creating another table in which the data would be grouped by different column ( by having a different primary key )? But this seems wasteful to me and I don't even know if that would help...

Or maybe I could use some staging table? Insert there 1,000,000 rows and then insert them to the target table, grouped up by the primary key?

Am I doomed?

EDIT:

I've partitioned the table horizontally.

When I removed the primary key on this field that I need and placed it on the autoincrement field, the inserts were blazingly fast.

Unfortunately, since the data on disk is placed by the primary key value, this killed the select performance... because selects don't query based on the autoincrement value but rather on the PK value.

So either I insert rows fast or I select them fast. Isn't there any solution that could help in both cases?

Comment: Do you really use whole table of 1b records? If not - then use [horizontal partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) and split your table into parts. Implementation of that depends of your DBMS (you've tagged two of them)

Comment: How do you know that 'the overhead of recounting the primary index, kills the performance'? Partitioning sounds the way to go.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag questions appropriately.

Comment: Another quick and easy solution is increase your IO stick the datastore on a couple of raided ssd's.

Comment: I've partitioned the table horizontally. When I removed the primary key on this field that I need and placed it on the autoincrement field, the inserts were blazingly fast. Unfortunately, since the data on disk is placed by the primary key value, this killed the select performance... because selects don't query based on the autoincrement value but rather on the PK value. So either I insert rows fast or I select them fast. Isn't there any solution that could help in both cases?

Comment: LOCK the index before you do the insert. Are you inserting them one at a time or in bulk?

Comment: Yeah I insert them in bulks of 50,000-70,000 rows and use transactions for this but still all I can "get" is around 70 inserts per second whereas with the autoincrement PK I get up to 5000 inserts per second ( but then SELECTs are slower and IOPS bound )

Comment: Is this a logging table? If I am right I would add a timestamp and all records below date X (leave 100k result set or so) should be mysql dumped, zipped, stored and dropped from the db. So much data is not useful in anyway, especially when you are going to fetch some results. Who wants to read all of that? MySQL can handle alot of data but a billion is not the right database anymore for such amount of data.

Comment: @Steini unfortunately I need to fetch the data from whole table, randomly :(

Comment: Well I would say you reached the limits of what MySQL is capable of then. Do you expect the data to become even more the next time? Then I would look arround for another solution, maybe Oracle or whatever is there arround...

Comment: create a secondary index on your old PK columm?

Answer (score 0):

.When you insert new row each time it will do indexing after data insert. It's take more time. 
You can use

START TRANSACTION

...You r insert query...

COMMIT

Comment: I use this to insert 50,000-70,000 rows per transaction and it still doesn't help much... What is the upper bound of amount of rows I could fit here? Maybe with bigger amounts, the mysql optimizer could better manage the disk IO since more rows could be grouped by PK's?

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

your insert query

mysql_query("COMMIT");